# This appear after login with SSH: * Overheard at KubeCon: "microk8s.status just blew my mind"

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh

Anyone knows what does this message means? It started to appear after SSH login in a server Ubuntu 16.04. This is wierd Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That message is generated by the MOTD (Message of the Day) when you log into a system via ssh.  That message is actually generated from `/etc/update-motd.d/50-motd-news` by pulling the text from https://motd.ubuntu.com/

Example:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ /etc/update-motd.d/50-motd-news 

 * Overheard at KubeCon: "microk8s.status just blew my mind".

     https://microk8s.io/docs/commands#microk8s.status
```

To configure if you see the news or not or if you want it to show something of your own look at editing `/etc/default/motd-news` where it is stated:

```
# This is a useful way to provide dynamic, informative
# information pertinent to the users and administrators
# of the local system
```

Comment: I do think that "nothing to worry about" is inappropriate in an answer, Answers should be kept factual and not based on personal opinion. Some people do not like arbitrary automated processes making connections to the internet.

Comment: It also seems reasonable that one might be "worried" about not wanting to be forced to look at an arbitrary message over which they have no control every time they log into their system.
Disable this by editing /etc/default/motd-news
Set ENABLED=0

Comment: To turn it off, edit /etc/default/motd-news and set `ENABLED=0`